# Funcion: Conversion de Decimal a Binario en C

Tags: c, funciones, punteros, function

estoy armando un programa en C que lee un numero entero, ingresado por teclado, y lo devuelve como numero binario.

Mi idea es usar un puntero para almacenar progresivamente los restos de la división entera en un vector. Mientras que el resultado de la función actúa como indicador para finalizar el bucle **while**.

aqui va el código

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int decabin(int n, int *R){

    *R = n%2;               //almaceno el resto en R
    return (n - *R)/2;
}

int main(){
    int B[100];     //tamaño arbitrario, por no dejar vacio el corchete
    int n;
    int R;
    printf("Ingrese un entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    int i = 0;
    while( n >= 2 ){            //el bucle finaliza cuando ya no es posible seguir dividiendo por 2
        n = decabin( n, &R );
        B[i] = R;     //armo el vector con los restos de las divisiones
        i++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    for( j; j<=i; j++ ){      //imprime todos los elementos almacenados en el vector
        printf("%i", B[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El problema que estoy experimentando es que como resultado me da cualquier cosa. Creo que estoy cometiendo algun error con el puntero *R

Comment: acabo de ejecutar el código y al parecer vi que los arreglos donde se encuentra i,j,100 están mal, al quitarlos me salio 0000 lo intente con 8 como numero entero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El número tres en binario es `11`, pero tu programa da como resulado `10`, eso es porque en el bucle compruebas que el retorno de `decabin` sea mayor o igual a dos:

```
scanf("%i", &n);

int i = 0;
while( n >= 2 ){            //el bucle finaliza cuando ya no es posible seguir dividiendo por 2
    n = decabin( n, &R );
    B[i] = R;     //armo el vector con los restos de las divisiones
    i++;
}
```

Así que sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Con `n` siendo `3`, la llamada a `decabin` guarda `1` en `R` y guarda `1` en `n`.
2. Dado que `n` no es mayor o igual a `2` no da otra vuelta. La variable `i` contiene `1`.

Después, en el bucle de impresión, imprimes un valor de más, porque comparas que el límite sea menor o igual a `i`:

```
int j = 0;
for( j; j<=i; j++ ){      //imprime todos los elementos almacenados en el vector
    printf("%i", B[j]);
}
```

Por lo que sigue los siguientes pasos:

1. Con `j` siendo `0`, su valor es menor o igual a `i`, que es `1`, imprime la posición `0` de `B`, que contiene `1`.
2. Con `j` siendo `1`, su valor es menor o igual a `i`, que es `1`, imprime la posición `1` de `B`, **que no ha sido escrita** y podría contener un valor cualquiera.

Debes cambiar tanto tu condición del bucle `while` como la del bucle `for` de impresión:

```
int i = 0;
while( n ){ // Cuando n sea 0, se acaba el bucle porque 0 equivale a "falso".
    n = decabin( n, &R );
    B[i] = R;     //armo el vector con los restos de las divisiones
    i++;
}

for(int j = 0; j<i; j++ ){ // Se indexa desde 0, así que debemos comprobar por "menor", no por "menor o igual"
    printf("%i", B[j]);
}
```

Pero esto te da el resultado al revés (ocho se vería como `001`), así que deberías imprimir al reves:

```
for(int j = i - 1; j>=0; j-- ){ // También podriamos comprobar j>-1
    printf("%i", B[j]);
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. No usas ninguna utilidad de `<math.h>`, no deberías incluir esa cabecera.
2. Deberías usar nombres de variables más claros y autoexplicativos, nombres como `n`, `i`, `R`, `B` o `j` no dan ninguna información sobre su utilidad.
3. El tamaño de la formación `B` no tiene por que ser arbitrario, si un byte tiene ocho bits sabremos que un `int` jamás necesitará más de `sizeof(int) * 8` dígitos binarios , el tamaño podría ser `B[sizeof(int) * 8];`.
4. No pasa nada por declarar las variables de los bucles `for` en el propio bucle.
5. [Favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).

Teniendo en cuenta todo eso, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int decabin(int valor, int *digito) {
    *digito = valor % 2;
    return (valor - *digito) / 2;
}

int main(){
    int buffer[sizeof(int) * 8];
    int valor;
    int digito;
    printf("Ingrese un entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &valor);

    int longitud = 0;
    for (; valor; ++longitud) {
        valor = decabin( valor, &digito );
        buffer[longitud] = digito;
    }

    for (int indice = longitud - 1; indice >= 0; --indice) {
        printf("%i", buffer[indice]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero yo personalmente, optaría por una solución mucho más corta usando recursividad:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void decabin (int n) {
    if (n) {
        decabin(n / 2);
        printf("%d", n % 2);
    }
}

int main(){
    int numero;
    printf("Ingrese un entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &numero);

    decabin(numero);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Para empezar, la función `decabin` es incorrecta. La función solo tiene que hacer dos cosas:

- Obtener el valor del bit menos significativo del número
- Eliminar dicho bit en el valor devuelto

Es decir:

```
int decabin(int n, int *R){

    *R = n%2;
    return n/2;
}
```

El siguiente error lo encontramos en el bucle `while`. Estás limitando el bucle a que `n` sea mayor o igual a 2 ... ¿Y si es 1? ¿Ese dígito no tiene que incluirse en la secuencia binaria? ¿de verdad?

El bucle debería quedar así:

```
int i;
for( i=0; n!=0; i++ )
{
    n = decabin( n, &R );
    B[i] = R;
}
```

O, evitando el uso innecesario de `R`:

```
int i;
for( i=0; n!=0; i++ )
{
    n = decabin( n, &B[i] );
}
```

El último error lo encontramos en el bucle final. La secuencia binaria que se obtiene **está invertida**, es decir, el bit más significativo se obtiene al final. Así que ese bucle tiene que ser decreciente:

```
for( int j = i-1; j>=0; j-- ){
    printf("%i", B[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solo hice un par de modificaciones a tu código y funciona, ten en cuenta que el numero binario lo estas escribiendo de forma LSB-first, el bit menos significativo primero, asi el número `8`, lo estas imprimiendo como `0001`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int decabin(int n, int *R){

    *R = n%2;               //almaceno el resto en R
    return (n - *R)/2;
}


int main()
{
    int B[100];     //tamaño arbitrario, por no dejar vacio el corchete
    int n;
    int R;
    printf("Ingrese un entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    int i = 0;
    /* **** MIENTRAS N SEA MAYOR A 0, NO A 2 **** */
    while( n > 0 ){            //el bucle finaliza cuando ya no es posible seguir dividiendo por 2
        n = decabin( n, &R );
        B[i] = R;     //armo el vector con los restos de las divisiones
        i++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    /* **** MIENTRAS j SEA MENOR A (i-1), NO A i **** */
    for( j; j<=i-1; j++ ){      //imprime todos los elementos almacenados en el vector
        printf("%i", B[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, puedes hacer uso de los operadores binarios *and* (`&`) y *left shift* (`>>`) para tu objetivo así, siendo esto más eficiente que las operaciones división y módulo (Aunque el compilador podría optimizarlo):

```
int decabin(int n, int *R){
    *R = n & 0x01;
    return (n >> 1);
}
```

Comment: Eso de la eficiencia que comentas funcionaba con compiladores de hace 30 años... los de hoy en día generan el mismo binario ante una división entre 2 y un desplazamiento de bits como el que comentas

Comment: Vale. Sabes si en cuanto al operador módulo también?

Comment: Efectivamente, también se. La operación de división, en los sistemas modernos, calcula también el módulo, luego si pones las dos operaciones juntas se calculan a la vez en una única instrucción ensamblador. Puedes ver un ejemplo [aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/zuVoU-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int decabin(int n, int *R){

    *R = n%2;               //almaceno el resto en R
    return (n - *R)/2;
}

int main(){
    int B;     //tamaño arbitrario, por no dejar vació el corchete
    int n;
    int R;
    printf("Ingrese un entero: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);

    int i = 0;
    while( n >= 2 ){            //el bucle finaliza cuando ya no es posible seguir dividiendo por 2
        n = decabin( n, &R );
        B = R;     //armo el vector con los restos de las divisiones
        i++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    for( j; j<=i; j++ ){      //imprime todos los elementos almacenados en el vector
        printf("%d", B);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Intente quitar el valor que le habías puesto al arreglo B como 100 y también a los demás arreglos de B pienso que estaba mal y arrojaba cualquier por que estaban mal usados los arreglos en B al quitarlos use como numero entero 12 y me dio como resultado 1111 espero que esa sea la solución saludos

Comment: ¿Desde cuando el binario de 12 da `1111`? Debería ser `1100`

Comment: Has dejado los comentarios de código que hablan de vectores habiendo eliminado todos los vectores del código... es decir: ¡has dejado comentarios fantasma!